# Phonegap App with Urban Airship Problems

Tags: xcode, cordova, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

Im trying to integrate Push Notifications in my iOS App. This is a Phonegap/Cordova Project. Everything is working well, without the APNS and Urban Airship.

What I have done till now? I got it to work, that I could send a Push Message from UA to my phone, but that was done with sample code from different forums and not the UA docs. So I startet to do it like in the docs of UA is showed. With that Im very confused and tried a lot.

So i did following:Took the Push Sample from UA and copied the code to AppDelegate.m what looks now like this:

```
 // Create Airship singleton that's used to talk to Urban Airhship servers.
    // Please populate AirshipConfig.plist with your info from http://go.urbanairship.com
    [UAirship takeOff:takeOffOptions];

    [[UAPush shared] resetBadge];//zero badge on startup

    [[UAPush shared] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                         UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
                                                         UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

    return YES;
}


- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    UALOG(@"Application did become active.");
    [[UAPush shared] resetBadge]; //zero badge when resuming from background (iOS 4+)
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    UALOG(@"APN device token: %@", deviceToken);
    // Updates the device token and registers the token with UA
    [[UAPush shared] registerDeviceToken:deviceToken];


    /*
     * Some example cases where user notification may be warranted
     *
     * This code will alert users who try to enable notifications
     * from the settings screen, but cannot do so because
     * notications are disabled in some capacity through the settings
     * app.
     * 
     */

    /*

     //Do something when notifications are disabled altogther
     if ([application enabledRemoteNotificationTypes] == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone) {
     UALOG(@"iOS Registered a device token, but nothing is enabled!");

     //only alert if this is the first registration, or if push has just been
     //re-enabled
     if ([UAirship shared].deviceToken != nil) { //already been set this session
     NSString* okStr = @"OK";
     NSString* errorMessage =
     @"Unable to turn on notifications. Use the \"Settings\" app to enable notifications.";
     NSString *errorTitle = @"Error";
     UIAlertView *someError = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:errorTitle
     message:errorMessage
     delegate:nil
     cancelButtonTitle:okStr
     otherButtonTitles:nil];

     [someError show];
     [someError release];
     }

     //Do something when some notification types are disabled
     } else if ([application enabledRemoteNotificationTypes] != [UAPush shared].notificationTypes) {

     UALOG(@"Failed to register a device token with the requested services. Your notifications may be turned off.");

     //only alert if this is the first registration, or if push has just been
     //re-enabled
     if ([UAirship shared].deviceToken != nil) { //already been set this session

     UIRemoteNotificationType disabledTypes = [application enabledRemoteNotificationTypes] ^ [UAPush shared].notificationTypes;



     NSString* okStr = @"OK";
     NSString* errorMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unable to turn on %@. Use the \"Settings\" app to enable these notifications.", [UAPush pushTypeString:disabledTypes]];
     NSString *errorTitle = @"Error";
     UIAlertView *someError = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:errorTitle
     message:errorMessage
     delegate:nil
     cancelButtonTitle:okStr
     otherButtonTitles:nil];

     [someError show];
     [someError release];
     }
     }

     */
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *) error {
    UALOG(@"Failed To Register For Remote Notifications With Error: %@", error);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    UALOG(@"Received remote notification: %@", userInfo);

    // Get application state for iOS4.x+ devices, otherwise assume active
    UIApplicationState appState = UIApplicationStateActive;
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(applicationState)]) {
        appState = application.applicationState;
    }

    [[UAPush shared] handleNotification:userInfo applicationState:appState];
    [[UAPush shared] resetBadge]; // zero badge after push received
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    [UAirship land];
}
```

Its pretty the same like before, but given from UA. Then i copied the files from the other sources folder from the Push Sample into my phonegap folder Supported Files including the AirshipConfig.plist. Also I set the Header Search Paths in the Build Settings to the Airship folder, what i copied before into the xCode project folder.

Now I get the error (6) "Use of undeclared identifier 'UAPush'" in the AppDeledate.m file. What can I do now?

Thanks for some help...

Comment: I had a lot of problems with PhoneGap and UrbanAirship too. I ended up abandoning using them together when UrbanAirship told me they wouldn't support PhoneGap even tho I got the code from their site.

Answer (score 6):

You need to import both UAirship.h & UAPush.h in your AppDelegate.m

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "UAirship.h"
#import "UAPush.h"
```

This will get rid of your undeclared identifier issue. Silly Urban Airship forgot to put this in their Documentation

Comment: Can verify this as true, I have no idea why he hasnt accepted your answer...saved me major headaches, thanks! NOTE: As of 4/12/13 still not in the docs

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at Xtify push services, PhoneGap plugin is fully supported:

iOS:
http://developer.xtify.com/display/sdk/PhoneGap+for+iOS+Xtify+Integration+Guide

Android:
http://developer.xtify.com/display/sdk/PhoneGap+for+Android+Xtify+Integration+Guide